# How to get child sprite from Multiple Sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get spesific sprite like 'ArmL' from spritesheet with multiple mode.

I have lots of multiple sprites so I need to use like below;

How can i achieve that ?

```
Public Sprite[] itemArmors;

examplesprite.sprite=itemArmors[ArmL];
```

[image]

Comment: In editor or runtime?

Comment: in editor i need to drag and drop but i will code it ofc.

Comment: There are multiple ways [answers.unity.com/how-to-get-child-sprites-from-a-multiple-sprite](https://answers.unity.com/questions/591677/how-to-get-child-sprites-from-a-multiple-sprite-te.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag and drop ArmL into the inspector

```
    public Sprite[] itemArmors;

    examplesprite.sprite=itemArmors[0]; // refers to the first element in the itemArmours sprite array
```

in the inspector make sure that the first element you add to itemArmours is ArmL. This is called indexing. If you just want to get ArmL don't use an array and just use:

```
 public Sprite ArmL;
 examplesprite.sprite = ArmL;
```